# Is it possible to add fields into an RSA private Key?

Tags: format, key, rsa, private, der

The RSA structure is defined in [RFC 3447](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt), A.1.2 RSA private key syntax.
This section states that the RSA should be presented as:

`RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
          version           Version,
          modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
          publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
          privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
          prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
          prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
          exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
          exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
          coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
          otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
      }`

Is it possible to add additional fields other than the ones described above, for example a Serial Number?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because without context your question is meaningless, and off topic. It's a free world, you can create ASN1 objects containing anything you want.

Comment: I understand that an ASN1 object can contains many fields. The question is if it is legitimate to add any field and don't corrupt the file.
I've just tried to add and Integer field to the RSA structure and when I tried to verify this new key using OpenSSL I've got an error.
This means that you are not allowed to add everything you want to a RSA structure in this free world. Your answer is not helping.